# How can I allocate the width of my Dash Datatable in my dashboard?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am trying to retrofit a dashboard away from tableau and towards plotly dash.  I am able to recreate most of the graphs, pie charts, and scatter plots and lay them out on the dashboard appropriately.  I will admit that I am new to plotly and dash, therefore my approach to the layout of the datatables in the dashboard may not be the best.  I am open to suggestions.  My end goal is two have two tables side by side each containing a width of 6, totaling the max of 12 columns.  However, what I am getting is the table is stretching the full length of 12 columns, as opposed to staying at 6.

My Dependencies for the entire dashboard are as follows:(some dependencies are used in other parts of the dashboard)

from dash import Dash, dash_table
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

from turtle import bgcolor
from matplotlib.pyplot import title

My Code is as follows:

```
       app.layout = html.Div([
              html.Div([dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dash_table.DataTable(
                data=df_bu_convert.to_dict("records"),
                columns=[
                    {'name': "Business Unit", 'id': 'Business Unit','type': 'text', 'editable':False},
                    {'name': "Ticket Count", 'id': 'Ticket Count','type': 'numeric', 'editable':False},
                        ],
                ), width =6)
              ])])
        ])

       if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This approach worked really well for graphs and plots. But, I can not get it to work for data tables. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below code for you case. I think you should use `external_stylesheets` as `dbc.themes` and dbc.Col should be added `[]`.

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dash_table.DataTable(
                data=[df_bu_convert.to_dict("records")],
                columns=[
                    {'name': "Business Unit", 'id': 'Business Unit','type': 'text', 'editable':False},
                    {'name': "Ticket Count", 'id': 'Ticket Count','type': 'numeric', 'editable':False}])
              ],width=6)
    ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run_server(debug=False,port=8122)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did add the style sheets and added the [] for dbc.col. It worked. I appreciate your help.